# Insert alphanumeric code for every row in SQL Python

Tags: python, sql, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to get my python script to add an 8 digit alphanumeric string for every row in my SQL Table.

I have tried:

```
x = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=8))
sql = "Update id_kom SET code = '"+ x + "'" 


try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: {}".format(e))
    raise e
    pass
```

It worked, but the "code" column was the same for every row.

Results before:

```
id  nr_tel     code
(1, 798------, NULL),
(2, 513------, NULL);
```

After:

```
id  nr_tel      code
(1, 798------, '3oKgiM86'),
(2, 513------, '3oKgiM86');
```

What I wanted:

```
id  nr_tel     code
(1, 798------, '3oKgiM86'),
(2, 513------, '1qResfYB');
```

And so on...

How can I make the script set the string different for every row?

## UPDATE

I also tried doing this:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()

updates = []
for row in rows:
    x = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=8))
    updates.append(x)

try:
    for code, id in updates:
        sql = "Update id_kom SET code = '{0}' WHERE id={1}".format(code, id) 
        cursor.execute(sql)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: {}".format(e))
    raise e
```

But I got an error: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: In your updated implementation you are appending a _single_ string to the `updates` list. You should be appending the code *and* the id of the row you want to update. Ex: `updates.append((x, row.id))`

Comment: @StevenGraham, `Exception has occurred: AttributeError'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'`, Perhaps you meant `row['id']`?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but I got the result I wanted converting the result from a tuple to a list of dicts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try addressing each row separately, like this:

```
updates = [('3oKgiM86', 1), ('1qResfYB', 2)]

try:
    for code, id in updates:
        sql = "Update id_kom SET code = '{0}' WHERE id={1}".format(code, id) 
        cursor.execute(sql)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: {}".format(e))
    raise e
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post: I have a set variable that will create this string for me, I don't want to define it myself. I want to add a different code to every added row in the table.
I use:
`x = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=8))`

Comment: Ok, but the main point of the answer still holds: you'd have to address each row separately if you want each row to get a different code.